# I downloaded Ubuntu but I can't find the ISO file

Tags: iso

I have downloaded Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop.

In order to create a bootable DVD it is asking for an ISO image which I haven't found in the download folder.

Where is the .iso file?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The iso is what you downloaded... The file you opened which contains the files you screenshotted - that's the iso.

Comment: Tim is totally right.  Windows hides file extensions (just in case you didn't know) and it looks like you have some kind op plugin that manages to open them in Windows Explorer.So, give us a screenshot of D:\Ubuntu insteadAlso, go enable extensions.

Comment: Or you may have unpacked the ISO to a folder.

Comment: Your utorrent program is probably set to open the downloaded content upon finishing the download job. And it opens the iso file with Windows Explorer, because the iso file-type is associated to Win Explorer. That's why you see the actual content of the iso file, and not the iso itself. Go one level up in Win Explorer and you will see the iso file.

Comment: @jawtheshark Windows 8 and later can natively mount ISOs.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Except of course this is clearly Windows 7.

Comment: @jawtheshark so it is. I think newer updates of 7 do treat ISOs as ZIPs.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Windows 7 never supported native ISO mounting. That was for 8 and upwards. The only program that lets you read ISO files (from the must have ones) is WinRAR but not by default. You will have to [`Select all` after installation](http://tips.betdownload.com/cf/images/ndh/2013/11/guide-to-install-winrar-the-file-compression-and-extraction-software1.jpg)

Comment: @PanagiotisTabakis yes, but on second glance, it looks like the OP opened the ISO as if it was a ZIP, since that's what the Windows 7 ZIP browser looks like.

Comment: @Zacharee1 yes indeed. But normally ISO files open with Disc Image Burner in Windows 7, but there is a case where if you have never used it or run it at least once so it gets auto-associated, ISO's will be extracted (via zip extraction) and browsed with Windows Explorer if you double click them. Add that the user couldn't see the .iso extension, mistakenly thinking it is a folder.

Answer (score 14):

According to your [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jiz4.png) you have actually mounted the .iso file and are browsing its contents.

As @ipse-lute correctly [pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/813471/downloaded-the-ubuntu-but-no-iso#comment1230653_813471):

> [...]Your uTorrent program is probably set to open the downloaded
>   content (either upon completion or by double-click) with Windows
>   Explorer, because the ISO file-type is associated to Windows Explorer
>   by default.[...]
>   Go one level up in Windows Explorer and you will see the ISO file.

Navigate to `D:\Ubuntu` and there will be a file named `ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso`. This is the ISO file you downloaded.

My guess is that you have `Hide extensions for known file types` ON, thus you cannot see the .iso extension on the file (*default behavior on windows)*.

In order to view file extensions:

- Start Windows Explorer, you can do this by opening up any folder.
- Click **Organize**.
- Click **Folder and search options**.
- Click the **View** tab.
- Scroll down until you find **Hide extensions for known file types**,
- Un-check it by clicking the check box.
  *Note To hide file name extensions, check this line.*
- Click **OK**

Answer (score 1):

Also beware that Windows 10 will hide a mounted `.iso` file while it's mounted. In that case users will want to go to My Computer, eject/unmount the Ubuntu disk, then go back to their Downloads directory and they can find the `.iso` file again and use `Burn Disk Image`

Answer (score 1):

If downloading on Windows, download on chrome, not on edge.  Edge will read the iso as a Disk, or even a disk drive instead of a disk burn image.  The default location in the dir is in Downloads for edge.
Try using Chrome instead, so it will ask you which dir to put it in

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too,copy and paste the download link in downloadmanager apps,then download it .u will see the iso file .

Comment: There is no need to use a 3rd party program such as a download manager to download Ubuntu though. The file downloaded is the iso file itself. Same result as shown will happen again if the asking user double clicks or open automatically the file once downloaded - windows just mounts it. It is still available as an iso file at the chosen download directory.