# I downloaded Lubuntu, but can't burn the ISO file

Tags: lubuntu, iso

From what I've read I am seeing all the files inside of the iso. I can't burn the iso to a disk this way though. I'm not too familiar with all this stuff. I inserted a dvd+rw and then the computer asked if I wanted to us e it like a usb or cd/dvd. I selected cd/dvd, then I dragged all the files to it and clicked burn. I inserted it into the disk drive, hit F12, but get no option to boot from disk drive. I don't know if the dvd didn't burn properly and maybe that's why I don't get the option to boot from it

Comment: What operating system are you using and which version?

Comment: windows 10 don't know which version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using a recent version of Windows, right click the `.iso` file and select `Burn Disk Image`

Also beware that Windows 10 now has the ability to mount disk images as the default option. When a disk image is mounted it will hide it from the file system. If you are unable to find the `.iso` file you downloaded check My Computer to ensure the disk isn't mounted and if it is eject/unmount it first.

Comment: that's the thing, there is no iso image

Comment: You probably have file name extensions disabled by default in Windows.

Comment: how do I enable?

Comment: You said in your original post "files inside the iso" right click whatever contains those files.

Comment: no option to burn. I  get expand, scan with windows defender, open in new window, pin to start, eject, etc....

Comment: this guy had the same problem. Didn't really get an answer. https://askubuntu.com/questions/813471/i-downloaded-ubuntu-but-i-cant-find-the-iso-file

Comment: The answers in that question are appropriate. It's entirely possible you are having the same problem as him.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83826/discussion-between-luigi-and-kristopher-ives).