# Where can I download Iso file of ubuntu

Tags: downloads

I want to get a iso file, i just want to get the iso file but it keeps downloading this folder, I just want the iso file not entire folder with 2 gb of content

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "entire folder". What is wrong with https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop ?!

Comment: Yes I do but instead of iso file i get a folder

Comment: May be you have a wrong browser configuration that directly opens the ISO as an archive instead of saving it as a file. Try right-click on the link -> "Save Link as"

Comment: when using the bittorrent option it downloads an iso, you may want to try that

Comment: ([via](https://askubuntu.com/a/1079406/631600)) *"Windows 10 will hide a mounted .iso file while it's mounted"*  ---  REALLY Microsoft ??? **That** is the cause for questions like this...

Comment: Windows can show iso file as a folder.

Answer (score 1):

The ubuntu isos are as Kristian says at https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

If you then need it to install it on a computer, you use a boot program like rufus.

Depending on the answers you say there may be two solutions.

1. Have you tried to download the iso from another device? The folder comes out with extension .iso? If not, you could do the following.
   Do you have the windows operating system? In Windows you install the UltraISO program that can convert the "folders" into an iso that were originally as shown in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3VF88qjy4w

2. If you install internet explorer as this page indicates:

https://www.atareao.es/software/internet/instalar-internet-explorer-en-ubuntu/

Then try from this browser to download the iso but instead of saving you give it to "save as" and put the extension .iso at the end with the name you want.

Answer (score 0):

https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=18.04.3&architecture=amd64

it should begin downloading after you click this link

Comment: Thats where i tried to download it but i got a folder

Comment: what browser are you using?